# Databricks Spark streaming from Kafka creates empty delta records

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, azure-databricks, spark-structured-streaming

We are trying to implement a streaming ingestion from Kafka using Databricks.
Here is our Spark job:

```
# Databricks notebook source
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import current_timestamp
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType, BooleanType, DoubleType, LongType

# COMMAND ----------

spark_depenedencies_jars = [ 
    "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:3.3.1",
    "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:3.3.1",
    "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.1",
    "org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.3.1",
    "org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.3.1",
    "io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.2.0"
]
spark_depenedencies_jars_str = ",".join(spark_depenedencies_jars)

# COMMAND ----------

KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS = "10.0.0.91:9094"
BASE_CHECKPOINT_LOCATION = "wasbs://warehouse@miniobucketsphera.blob.core.windows.net/checkpoint/"
BASE_DELTA_DIR_VM_AZURE = "wasbs://warehouse@miniobucketsphera.blob.core.windows.net/delta/inventory/"

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("Kafka Streaming Example") \
    .master(SPARK_MASTER_LOCAL) \
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog") \
    .config("spark.databricks.delta.retentionDurationCheck.enabled", "false") \
    .config("spark.hadoop.hive.metastore.uris", HIVE_METASTORE_URI) \
    .config("spark.sql.catalogImplementation", "hive") \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()
   
df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save(delta_wasbs_path)

# COMMAND ----------

# .writeStream \ test

def read_kafka_stream(kafka_topic, schema):
    kafka_stream = spark \
                .readStream \
                .format("kafka") \
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS) \
                .option("subscribe", kafka_topic) \
                .option("failOnDataLoss","false") \
                .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
                .load()
    data_stream = kafka_stream.selectExpr("cast (value as string) as json") \
                            .select(from_json("json", schema).alias("cdc")) \
                            .select("cdc.payload.after.*", "cdc.payload.op")
    data_stream = data_stream.withColumn("curr_timestamp", current_timestamp())
    return data_stream

# COMMAND ----------

# .save() test

def write_delta_table(data_stream, checkpoint_location, delta_dir):
    data_stream.writeStream \
                .format("delta") \
                .outputMode("append") \
                .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_location) \
                .start(delta_dir)

# COMMAND ----------

from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType

schema_table_schema = StructType([
    StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("age", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("name", StringType(), True),
])

source_schema = StructType([
    StructField("version", StringType(), False),
    StructField("connector", StringType(), False),
    StructField("name", StringType(), False),
    StructField("ts_ms", IntegerType(), False),
    StructField("snapshot", StringType(), True),
    StructField("db", StringType(), False),
    StructField("sequence", StringType(), True),
    StructField("table", StringType(), True),
    StructField("server_id", IntegerType(), False),
    StructField("gtid", StringType(), True),
    StructField("file", StringType(), False),
    StructField("pos", IntegerType(), False),
    StructField("row", IntegerType(), False),
    StructField("thread", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("query", StringType(), True),
])

transaction_schema = StructType([
    StructField("id", StringType(), False),
    StructField("total_order", IntegerType(), False),
    StructField("data_collection_order", IntegerType(), False),
])

schema_payload_schema = StructType([
    StructField("before", schema_table_schema, True),
    StructField("after", schema_table_schema, True),
    StructField("source", source_schema, True),
    StructField("op", StringType(), False),
    StructField("ts_ms", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("transaction", transaction_schema, True),
])

schema_schema = StructType([
    StructField("schema", StringType(), True),
    StructField("payload", schema_payload_schema, True),
])


# COMMAND ----------

schema_table_topic = "sqlf-eus-sccspoc-dev.schema1.table1"


# COMMAND ----------

schema_table_checkpoint_location = BASE_CHECKPOINT_LOCATION + "schema_table"


# COMMAND ----------

schema_table_delta_dir = BASE_DELTA_DIR_VM_AZURE + "schema_table"


# COMMAND ----------

schema_table_stream = read_kafka_stream(schema_table_topic, schema_schema)


# COMMAND ----------

write_delta_table(schema_table_stream, schema_table_checkpoint_location, schema_table_delta_dir)
```

We are able to see parquet partitions being created, but they are empty (only metadata but no real data)

[image: empty deltatable]

Have anyone encountered a similar issue?
If so - what was the resolution?

Comment: Seems like you are using Debezium? I'd recommend [doing this](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/transformations/event-flattening.html) rather than use schema+payload fields

Comment: But to debug, I suggest you show your read Kafka DF output... If the data is null from Kafka dataframe, then it'll also be null in Delta/Parquet output

Comment: you don't need all these `spark.sql.extensions`, etc. If you use notebooks, then `spark` is initialized, and Delta, Kafka, Hive, etc. is already shipped.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't encountered the issue but intrigued by the question, found this [answer in Databricks Knowledge Base](https://kb.databricks.com/en_US/delta/delta-writing-empty-files-when-source-is-empty):

> If your streaming application is writing to a target Delta table and your source data is empty on certain micro batches, it can result in writing empty files to your target Delta table.
> ...
>
> Solution
>
> You should upgrade your clusters to Databricks Runtime 9.1 LTS or above.
> Databricks Runtime 9.1 LTS and above contains a fix for the issue and no longer creates empty files for empty writes.

If you can't upgrade, there is another workaround:

> If you cannot upgrade to Databricks Runtime 9.1 LTS or above, you should periodically run OPTIMIZE (AWS | Azure | GCP) on the affected table to clean up the empty files. This is not a permanent fix and should be considered a workaround until you can upgrade to a newer runtime.

For a more Spark-based solution, there is a configuration flag `spark.sql.streaming.noDataMicroBatches.enabled`. It's used in the `MicroBatchExecution`:

```
  private def constructNextBatch(noDataBatchesEnabled: Boolean): Boolean = withProgressLocked {
    if (isCurrentBatchConstructed) return true
// ...
    val lastExecutionRequiresAnotherBatch = noDataBatchesEnabled &&
      Option(lastExecution).exists(_.shouldRunAnotherBatch(offsetSeqMetadata))
    val shouldConstructNextBatch = isNewDataAvailable || lastExecutionRequiresAnotherBatch
//..

  protected def runActivatedStream(sparkSessionForStream: SparkSession): Unit = {
// ...
          // Try to construct the next batch. This will return true only if the next batch is
          // ready and runnable. Note that the current batch may be runnable even without
          // new data to process as `constructNextBatch` may decide to run a batch for
          // state cleanup, etc. `isNewDataAvailable` will be updated to reflect whether new data
          // is available or not.
          if (!isCurrentBatchConstructed) {
            isCurrentBatchConstructed = constructNextBatch(noDataBatchesEnabled)
          }

// ...
          currentStatus = currentStatus.copy(isDataAvailable = isNewDataAvailable)
          if (isCurrentBatchConstructed) {
            if (currentBatchHasNewData) updateStatusMessage("Processing new data")
            else updateStatusMessage("No new data but cleaning up state")
            runBatch(sparkSessionForStream)
          } else {
            updateStatusMessage("Waiting for data to arrive")
          }
```

Of course, it won't help if the empty files are the result of your transformations, e.g. if you filtered out all the input rows. In that case, the `OPTIMIZE` or the runtime upgrade should help.

Please notice that when you disable the emptiness flag, you will impact stateful operations but since your pipeline doesn't use them, you should be fin.